# VBA. How to quickly get total number of open documents in Application.Documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an word.application as an object in VBA and I want something that works like:

```
if word.application.documents(total) = 0 Then _
     word.application.quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
End If
```

So i can add documents to word.application if it already exists and close the document neatly, leaving all other documents intact, but if other documents have been closed in the mean time, then it will quit word completely rather than leaving a blank instance of word open for no reason.

To put it another way, without looping through all documents in application.documents(i) until it throws a "document does not exist" and at this point count the value of i.... is there a way to find out (i) instantly?

I'm sure its possible but the exact syntax to use is eluding me.
Also, for future reference, Im assuming documents property is some sort of array, is there a way to print to screen the values in a property or method?

Comment: `Word.Application.Documents.Count` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oWordApp.Documents.Count` is what you need to check.

Comment: Thank You. Is there a better resource than microsoft dev centre, coming from writing php and having access to the manual and the forums, I find the MS help to be a lot less useful in its examples and support

Comment: MSDN are usually for References. Examples will be hard to demonstrate all since it covers huge areas. You can get printed/digital materials on VBA of the office app you are interested in, they usually have more examples.